# cell phone extender for iphones

Tags: telephony

I need to boost the cell phone signal into a basement office. We are in a fringe area of the AT&T network, and can usually get two bars outside, but zero bars in the below grade offices.

Anyone have opinions on any of these devices (or something similar):

- [Wireless Extenders YX 500-Pcs Cellular Phone Signal Booster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000A3OLZC)
- [Wireless Extenders YX510-PCS-CEL Dual-Band Cell Phone Signal Booster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J2XZ1K)

BTW: This is for use with iPhones primarily, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT&T is currently running trials for their [MicroCell network extender](http://www.engadget.com/2009/01/25/details-on-atandts-3g-microcell-everything-but-the-date-and-pric/) that, when introduced, will let you make calls [on your iPhone](http://www.engadget.com/2009/02/07/iphone-carrier-update-hints-at-atandt-microcell-coming-soon/) through your broadband connection. No word on when it will be available though.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer my question, but I've accepted it, it does one better by keeping me from buying something else that will be obsolete when the MicroCell becomes available...can't wait. Any idea on how to get in on the trial?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the trial ended (or was supposed to end) on June 9th, so I don't think it's possible to get in on the trial at this time. I can only hope that it was successful, and that it will be announced/shipping soon. http://www.engadgetmobile.com/2009/04/08/atandt-3g-microcell-trials-starting-this-week-retail-in-june-or-l/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using an unlocked iPhone, neither of those devices you listed have AT&T as a supported carrier. I'm sure the iphone could roam onto those other networks, but what that would do to your bill, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you one more device to consider.  It's not as strong as the one's you found.  http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/cellphone/b8a0/

The dual band model product description does say AT&T as a support device. It should boost the 800/850MHz band which the iphone can operate on